# Renaming the entire application in android

Tags: android, eclipse, shortcut

I have an app I want to rename the entire application package name including the references of Customeviews in layout files. Is there any shortcut for this in Eclipse or can we write any scripts to modify the specific files.

Comment: Click on the file name in the Package Explorer, press **F2**.

Answer (score 0):

```
Right click the package in Eclipse -> Refactor -> Rename.
```

Comment: Hardcoded strings might not change it with just refactoring. But yes, @user448250 , definitely refactor, do a Find all text search through the project also

Comment: Eclipse can not relate hard coded string with package name..however android studio has some that kind intelligence built in..